# Swift iOS -Get dictionary to accept nil value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, null

I have an array that can hold up to 4 values. The array will always have at least 1 value but the other 3 may be nil. I have to take the elements inside the array and assign them to class properties.

The problem is once I iterate through the array, get nil values, assign them to the class properties and then try to assign those nil properties to my dictionary, I get a crash.

I need the dictionary to accept the values with colors and ignore the nil values. So I have 2 problems.

1. The colors from the array that do exist are coming up as nil in myDict
2. The nil values in the array are exceptions

How would I go about fixing this?

code:

```
class ColorClass{
    var colorOne:String?
    var colorTwo:String?
    var colorThree:String?
    var colorFour:String?
}

let colorClass = ColorClass()
var randColors: [String?] = []

//In this case I have 2 colors but sometimes randColors may have 1 color or 3 colors or 4 colors. It will always vary
randColors = ["purple","pink"]

for (index,element) in randColors.enumerate(){

    switch index {
    case 0:
        if let elZero = element{
            colorClass.colorOne = elZero
        }
    case 1:
        if let elOne = element{
            colorClass.colorTwo = elOne
        }
    case 2:
        if let elTwo = element{
            colorClass.colorThree = elTwo
        }
    case 3:
        if let elThree = element{
            colorClass.colorFour = elThree
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}

var myDict = [String:AnyObject]()
myDict.updateValue(colorClass.colorOne!, forKey: "firstKey")
myDict.updateValue(colorClass.colorTwo!, forKey: "secondKey")
myDict.updateValue(colorClass.colorThree!, forKey: "thirdKey")
myDict.updateValue(colorClass.colorFour!, forKey: "fourthKey")
```

The crashes occur on:

```
myDict.updateValue(colorClass.colorThree!, forKey: "thirdKey")
myDict.updateValue(colorClass.colorFour!, forKey: "fourthKey")
```

Comment: Objects of type `[String:AnyObject]` can't have any `nil` values inside. However `[String:AnyObject ?]` can. So try changing the signature of myDict, so it looks like `var myDict = [String: AnyObject?]()` ... then if you need it as a nil, you can simply write `myDict.updateValue(nil, forKey: "yourKey")`

Comment: @ mutant keyboard Thanks for the help. I tried your solution but it didn't work. I changed the dict declaration to var myDict = [String: AnyObject?](). Also, I just realized the 2 color values that actually do exist are showing as nil values.

Comment: A `nil` value in a dictionary means that the corresponding key is missing. A declaration `[String:AnyObject?]` is nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if let` to ignore `nil` values while adding/updating the values in the dictionary.

```
if let clrThree = colorClass.colorThree {
     myDict.updateValue(clrThree, forKey: "thirdKey")
}

if let clrFour = colorClass.colorFour {
     myDict.updateValue(clrFour, forKey: "fourthKey")
}
```

**Reason of Crashes is,
you are using `!` after the `colorClass.colorFour` i.e. you are using as `colorClass.colorFour!`.**

> When swift finds the value of the variable as nil and try to
>   forcefully unwrap it the application will crash **unexpectedly found
>   nil while unwrapping**

Comment: Thanks. I tried putting it inside my switch statement but i get all nil values even for the correct colors like this --case 0:
        if let elZero = someClass.propertyOne{
            myDict.updateValue(elZero, forKey: "firstKey")
        } and case 3:
        if let elThree = someClass.propertyFour{
            myDict.updateValue(elThree, forKey: "fourthKey")
        } produces let colorOne = someClass.propertyOne (nil value)
let colorThree = someClass.propertyThree (ni values). I get no crashes but both are nil values and colorOne shouldn't be nil

Comment: Good answer. Two other options include using the nil coalesce operator and using the new default value for a dictionary to avoid the issue.